# Offline Application Development using Kendo UI

Tags: kendo-ui, offline-caching, offlineapps

I am trying to develop the application using Kendo UI. This will be html application using Kendo UI and the data will be provided by Web API.

The main purpose is i want this application to be offline enabled. Means if there is no internet connection then also it should serve the cached page.

By doing some research i came across [Kendo UI Offline Handling](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#transportread-objectstringfunction).

Here is my understanding by after refering the above link:

As per my thinking this approach will be used when the WEB API is off due to some reason but then also the html pages will serve the cached data contents. But to do this my html application should be working live ( using internet ).

Am i correct ?

If i am correct than what should i in order to make my application serve the user without internet connection ( offline mode ) using html and Kendo UI. ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To enable a web application to be useful offline you need to think about how to persist its data, such as application data, user data and session state, on the client. I suggest you do some research on the [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) and go from there.